# Something weird with Data Conversion between MQ explorer and remote QMGR

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i've got a question about data conversion between MQ Explorer and remote QMGR.

In order to reproduce the data conversion failure issue, i set the value of ccsid of remote QMGR as **9066**. **Since there is no conversion table for ccsid 9066 in system, i supposed that the connection from MQ explorer to QMGR would fail.** However, unfortunately,  that explorer still can add the QMGR in successfully.

Can you please help explain why it happened?

Thanks in advance

Please find related information as below:

```
-bash-4.1$ cd /opt/mqm/lib/iconv/
-bash-4.1$ ls | grep 236A    (note: the hex value of ccsid 9066 is 236A)
-bash-4.1$ echo dis qmgr ccsid | runmqsc QMGR01
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2005.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QMGR01.
     1 : dis qmgr ccsid
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QMGR01)                          CCSID(9066)
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.
-bash-4.1$ dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     6.0.2.12
CMVC level:  p600-212-121204
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
-bash-4.1$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-71.el6.i686 #1 SMP Fri Nov 12 04:17:17 GMT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ treats conversion of message headers and conversion of message data differently.  The headers are designed so that conversion is minimized and, where it is required, always uses characters that convert in all CCSIDs.  The intention is that two QMgrs or a client and a QMgr should be able connect, even in situations where payload data may not be convertible.  The fact that you could not get it to fail attests to the robustness of this approach.